# Can't use GNOME shell on VirtualBox

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, gnome

I am running version 11.10 on a VirtualBox VM with ~1000MB dedicated memory, on mid-range hardware and using Windows Vista as a host. It came with Unity pre-installed.
I ran:

```
apt-get install gnome-shell
```

When it was complete, I logged out from Unity, clicked on the Gear icon to select my UI and noticed that there was no trace of Gnome Shell:

[image: The only available options]

I tried selecting GNOME thinking that it could be the right one but I was presented with this desktop, which I don't believe to be the Gnome Shell Desktop:

[image: The desktop I was presented with]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: This looks like it's hitting the fallback mode, check to see if your hardware acceleration is set up in VB?

Comment: Specifically, make sure you have 3D acceleration turned on. Without it, I can't run GNOME Shell. It seems 2D acceleration doesn't matter as much here.

Comment: I enabled it, restarted the machine and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D Acceleration is "experimental" in VB and may not be properly supported. Also which version of Virtual Box are you using. The Open Source version doesn't seem to support all the functions of the one downloaded off the site.
I don't like suggesting closed source, but your situation may call for it.
Also I'm going to try running `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` on my 11.10 machine and see what it looks like. There's still the possibility that it's not VB.

Comment: Version is 4.1.4, I've enabled hardware acceleration but still no result.

Comment: Fixed it, I had to update to 4.1.4, reinstall the guest additions and remove and reinstall gnome-shell.

Answer (score 1):

A video describing the process for using the Gnome shell in Fedora 16 can be found at http://www.squidoo.com/enable-the-gnome-shell-in-fedora-16-and-virtual-box (it should be similar for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the Unity look in the VM you're wanting, try [Unity-2D](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D).
It uses QT and has none of the OpenGL requirements which are likely why you're unable to have Unity in the VM.
It looks almost exactly like Unity.